# Why is my unordered navigation list not displaying as inline?

Tags: html, css

I have tried creating a `div`, deleting the `div`, trying to get the `ul` displayed as `inline`, everything, but my unordered list is still not displaying as `inline`. What am I missing?

```css
p {
  font-family: orbitron;
}
h1 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: orbitron;
}
ul {
  dispaly: inline;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="navigation_bar">
    <li class="About">About Game</li>
    <li>Screenshots</li>
    <li>About creator</li>
    <li>Forums</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You’ve got a typo: `dispaly` should be `display`.

Answer (score 2):

Not the `ul` should be `inline`, the `li`s in the `ul` should be. Change your selector like this:

```css
ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

or this:

```css
ul > li {
  display: inline;
}
```

Also, you’ve got a typo: `dispaly` should be `display`.